# Bounties indicator in users profile (summary tab) has collapsed

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, design

I noticed that the CSS of the bounty indicator in users profile has gone. Furthemore i can not navigate through options(active/earned/offered).

The problem is on the summary tab under user accounts
Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Meta.SE report with temporary fix via the SOUP add-on: [Earned bounties layout is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239382)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed and it will be out in the next build (#2568)