# On bounties section of Stack Overflow profile sort select is mispositioned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounty

On bounties section of Stack Overflow profile sort select is mispositioned.

I am using Firefox 32.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

[image: Design example]

Comment: In chrome the first bounty seems to be positioned below that, but that doesn't look right either. (http://imgur.com/HY6w605)

Comment: It should not use a select box **at all**. This was already reported.

Comment: See [Earned bounties layout is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239382)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271402/bounties-indicator-in-users-profile-summary-tab-has-collapsed?rq=1